# Can the following equation be solved for the unknowns?

Tags: calculus

> $$f(x) = x^3 + bx^2 + c$$
>   A tangent line passes through the point $(-2,6)$. Solve for $b$ and $c$.

The above question was on our test, and our teacher insisted it was solvable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As given the problem is, I'm afraid, unsolvable. Perhaps you missed something about the tangent line's slope, or perhaps the point is an extreme point, or perhaps an inflection point...?

Comment: Teachers are not always right, but they often are. To decide, one would have to know the exact wording of the question. Of course as currently worded, it is far from determining $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

A tangent line passes through (-2,6) means that f(-2)=6 and f''(-2)=0 so you get $b=-3$ and $c=26$.

Comment: How did you get that $f''(-2) = 0$? The question doesn't say anything like that.

Comment: I understand it as it "the tangent passes through the curve", but maybe I understand it wrong.

Comment: But it doesn't say through the curve, it says through the point.

Comment: Yes the question is maybe incomplete otherwise there is not a unique answer.